# about ireport DetailBand disappear on Next page

Tags: java

help me solve this ,thanks!
my detailband disappear when nextpage
the detailband is comprised of subreport and line
while nextpage my detailband no showup
how can i do for this~

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHqnm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr9GB.jpg)

please help me to solve this!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Are you saying that your [Java?] code is not giving you your expected result? Maybe you can [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can reproduce your problem and subsequently try to debug it?